# Convert Array of Dictionary in single Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

This code:

```
server_response = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4}]
```

I am getting above response from server now I want only the list of ids in one array like

```
ids = [1,2,3,4];
```

I know we can do by for loop but it takes long time if thousand of ids inside the response array.

Is there any better way to achieve above equation?

Comment: if you want to see how to do it using loops: see this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414456/how-to-give-the-integer-key-value-for-dictionary/32414512?noredirect=1#comment52737940_32414512

Comment: id result = [array valueForKey:@"id"]

Comment: @Rog :: awesome ...thank you so much....

Comment: No worries I'll post it as an answer for future reference.

Comment: @Rog :: post as an answer so i will make it right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *result = [yourArray valueForKey:@"id"]
```

From the documentation for NSArray instance method `valueForKey:`

> Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dict in server_response) {

    [resultArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"id"]];
}
```

Try above code. Hope it will help you. Result array has final values

Comment: thank you but can we do without for loop becuase if a thousand of ids inside response array then complier take too much time for execution..

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *server_response =  @[@{@"id":@"1"},@{@"id":@"2"},@{@"id":@"3"},@{@"id":@"4"}];  

    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSString *birdtemp;
    for (NSDictionary *object in server_response) {
        birdtemp = object[@"id"];
        [resultArray addObject:birdtemp];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",resultArray);
```

OutPut: [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
]